# weird escape behaviour when writing string from node to mysql db

Tags: mysql, node.js, escaping

I'm on node and want to write this in my mysql db:

```
var x = JSON.stringify(['aa"a']);

console.log(x);

mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE `table` SET field = '" + x + "' WHERE id = 1");
```

The console.log() produces: ["aa\"a"]

When I read the string from the db later, I get: ["aa"a"]

The backslash is missing, making the string useless, as calling JSON.parse() would produce an error.

Comment: If you only know one thing about SQL, it should be this: **do not** build queries with string concatenation. Read the relevant library docs for how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're mashing your SQL together as a string. `\` is an escape character (in SQL as well as JSON), so it escapes the `"` when passed to the SQL engine.

Use placeholders (whichever MySQL API library you are using should have a way of using them) instead of manually shoving variables into the string of SQL.